# Symfony composer install - Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "SensioGeneratorBundle"

Tags: php, composer-php, symfony

Composer fails to install symfony in the production environment. Everything works fine in development. All permissions are fine.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "SensioGeneratorBundle" from namespace "Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /home/ev/app/AppKernel.php:25
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ev/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(396): AppKernel->registerBundles()
#1 /home/ev/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(114): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()
#2 /home/ev/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
#3 /home/ev/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(118): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 /home/ev/bin/console(27): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Inp in /home/ev/app/AppKernel.php on line 25
```

This is line 25 of AppKernel.php:

```
$bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
```

Any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: Probleme solved with this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41112773/9131185

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Prod environnment, the SensioGeneratorBundle is not registred.
This bundle should be defined like a dev bundle as follow :

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    }
```

And inside your composer file :

```
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
}
```

If you want to use generation commands from this bundle in Prod env, you should move the declaration from dev to Prod (not recommended!)

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my issue

Comment: i think it's as stated by @jeremy by default right ?

Answer (score 1):

This also depend of your goal:

- if you want to setup a prod env : run `composer install --no-dev` and `SYMFONY_ENV=prod` and the error should go away.

Answer (score 1):

in my case Sensio Generator Bundle is deprecated in Symfony 4, so you may
comment or delete this 2 lines below.

```
    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
         //$bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
        //$bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$ cd project_folder
$ composer dump-autoload
```

This reloads files and loads your settings.