# Heroku Symfony 3.2 Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app

Tags: php, heroku, symfony

I'm having trouble while deploying my symfony web app on heroku, when previously it worked just fine. What could be wrong?
This is the build log: http://pastebin.com/DXZH110S

Here is the relevant part of the log:

Generating optimized autoload files

> Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
>      Creating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
>      PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "SensioGeneratorBundle" from namespace "Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle".
>      Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /tmp/build_d39105bc4146e68631d1261a1ca2a632/izio7-YourTeam-15b2d72/app/AppKernel.php:25
>      Stack trace:
>      #0 /tmp/build_d39105bc4146e68631d1261a1ca2a632/izio7-YourTeam-15b2d72/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(403): AppKernel->registerBundles()
>      #1 /tmp/build_d39105bc4146e68631d1261a1ca2a632/izio7-YourTeam-15b2d72/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(113): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()
>      #2 /tmp/build_d39105bc4146e68631d1261a1ca2a632/izio7-YourTeam-15b2d72/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
>      #3 /tmp/build_d39105bc4146e68631d1261a1ca2a632/izio7-YourTeam-15b2d72/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Appli in /tmp/build_d39105bc4146e68631d1261a1ca2a632/izio7-YourTeam-15b2d72/app/AppKernel.php on line 25
>      Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception

```
 [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:                                                                                                                                                            
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "SensioGeneratorBundle" from namespace "Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle".                                                
 Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /tmp/build_d39105bc4146e68631d1261a1ca2a632/izio7-YourTeam-15b2d72/app/AppKernel.php:25                                                                                  
 Stack trace:                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 #0 /tmp/build_d39105bc4146e68631d1261a1ca2a632/izio7-YourTeam-15b2d72/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(403): AppKernel->registerBundles()                                                          
 #1 /tmp/build_d39105bc4146e68631d1261a1ca2a632/izio7-YourTeam-15b2d72/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(113): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()                              
 #2 /tmp/build_d39105bc4146e68631d1261a1ca2a632/izio7-YourTeam-15b2d72/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()                            
 #3 /tmp/build_d39105bc4146e68631d1261a1ca2a632/izio7-YourTeam-15b2d72/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Appli in /tmp/build_d39105bc4146e68631d1261a1ca2a632/izio7-YourTeam-15b2d72/app/AppKernel.php on line 25
```

Comment: I would recommend pasting the relevant part of the build log here, and steps you've taken to resolve any errors that came up, otherwise there's not a lot to go on here.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I solved, the problem was the system variable SYMFONY_ENV=prod not set.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-symfony#configuring-symfony-to-run-in-the-prod-environment